# git push not asking to set upstream even though upstream not set

Tags: git

I have `master` branch and I have the following configurations set.

```
branch.master.remote=github
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
push.default=simple
```

Now I wanted to test behaviour of `push.default`. I did

```
git branch master1 // This created a new branch on same commit as master
git checkout master1
git push github
```

Now, since my local branch name is `master1` and it is new branch , it does not have any upstream set with it. Why did not `git push github` showed me error message to use `--set-upstream` flag ?
Also, it successfully created `master1` branch on remote repo. Also, I see no remote tracking branch with it upon running `git branch -vv`

```
  master  42f18f8 [github/master] Some message
  master1 42f18f8 Some message
```

However, if I had just done `git push` while being on `master1` branch , then it asks for `--set-upstream`.

Also, I dont have `remote.github.push` or `remote.master1.push` set.

Comment: il you create a branch locallly, why would it track a upstream? imagine you have multiple remove which one would it be?

Comment: I m pushing to remote using `push.default` settings. This now needs a remote tracking branch.

Comment: this is not a matter of branch but a matter of remote. If you just `git push`, which remote is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the second paragraph of the `simple` docs:

> When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.

and you're pushing to a remote that is not the remote you normally pull from.  So it works as "current", "push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end".

Git's trying to avoid newbies doing unintentional damage while still being as helpful as possible, exactly what needs to be allowed or prevented by default is always going to be a bit befuddling because rookie mistakes are too.

Comment: For everybdy else reference , [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) is the `simple` doc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this in two parts.

#### `git push` and upstreams

First: `git push`, with no additional arguments, will (usually—depending on settings, which I won't go into here), looks at the upstream setting of the *current* branch.

If there isn't an upstream on the current branch, you get:

```
fatal: The current branch <branch> has no upstream branch.
```

(followed by configurable advice to use `git push --set-upstream`; if you configure it away, you won't get the advice).

If there is an upstream, you *don't* get that error.  That's all there really is to it.  If there *is* an upstream set, `git push` won't tell you to set one.  If not, it will give you an error, and (unless you've configured the advice away) suggest that you set one.

Second, `git push` *with additional arguments* behaves differently.  **Edit:** the next bit was wrong.  The crucial additional argument here was the `github` argument.  See [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58358279/1256452) for details.  I've left the rest in strikeout because it can apply in some situations as well.

<s>But you did not run:</s>

> ```
> git push github
> ```

You actually ran:

```
git push github master1
```

(Check your command history.)  If you supply a *refspec* argument, which this four-word `git push` command does, the *refspec* supplies the branch names—both the one used locally, and the one your Git requests that their Git set.  There's no need for the current branch, nor for any upstream settings of any branches.

#### `git branch` or `git checkout -b` and upstreams

Both `git branch` and `git checkout` can create new branch names.

A branch name can have an upstream set, or not set.

Therefore, when `git branch` or `git checkout` creates a new branch name, they have the *option* of setting an upstream.

Their actual behavior is configurable, using `branch.autoSetupMerge` and `branch.autoSetupRebase`.  Their *default* behavior, though, is this:

- If you don't supply a starting commit, use `HEAD` as the starting commit when creating the new branch, and do not set an upstream.
- If you *do* supply a starting commit, check the form of the supplied argument:

  - If it has the form of a remote-tracking name—which implies both the remote and the branch name as seen on that remote—set an upstream.
  - Otherwise, don't set an upstream.

Since `git branch master1` does not supply a starting commit, the new name is created using the hash ID to which `HEAD` resolves, and it has no upstream.  Hence your `git branch -vv` showed no upstream set.

#### Settings make things complicated

The exact details of all of the possible interactions between all the different settings (`push.default`, `remote.<name>.push`, and others) can mess with all of this.  I mention this primarily because you mentioned that you have not set any of these.  If you do, some or all of the above may be invalidated.  The Git documentation covers some, but not all possible, combinations.

Where it says that some combination is supposed to behave in some particular manner, it should behave that way.  Otherwise, it may behave in any way the Git coders felt was convenient for them.  Be careful when configuring options: some combinations have probably never been tested.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. I am sure I ran `git push github` and not `git push github master1`. See @jthill answer below and my comment there. He has hit the right spot but one thing is still missing to answer yet which I have asked in the comment.

Comment: Ah, you're right - I was entirely (or at least mostly) wrong!